# query data inside NoteBook chuncks

Tags: r

I am trying to query an SQL Express database with the method of using the chunk itself so that I do not have to format the SQL and this marks errors that I do not understand

````
```{r,sql, connection=con,output.var="df2"}
select 
Empleados.firstName + ' ' + Empleados.middleName + ' ' + Empleados.lastName as Jefe_Proyecto,
Planificadores.U_refproy as Proyecto, 
Planificadores.U_reffase as Fase
from [@ITAPROYSEG] Planificadores 
inner join OPRJ proyectos on Planificadores.U_refproy=Proyectos.PrjCode
inner join  OHEM Empleados on Planificadores.U_empid=Empleados.empID
inner join [@ITAPROYFASES] Fases on Planificadores.U_reffase=Fases.U_codfase
where Empleados.U_Activo='Sí' and Proyectos.U_prop1='Y'
order by Jefe_Proyecto, Proyecto, Fase
```
````

[image: error]

Any idea, please?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `r` in the chunk header!
The correct syntax is `{sql, connection=con, output.var="df2"}`

Comment: If I do it, the chunk options disappear, that is, I do not have the button to execute it

Comment: you still need to put the backticks ``` in front of it

Comment: I have this: 
```{sql, connection=con,output.var="df2"}